# APNS messages not received on iOS devices, but are sent

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have built an app and it has push notifications. I use a WordPress plugin to send the notifications, which are sent successfully, but are not received by my iOS devices.

I have a VPS server with port `2195`, `2196`, `5223` & `443` open TCP in & out. I have also allowed the entire `17.0.0.0/8` ip address block that Apple use for notifications.

I can telnet from my server to Apple and get a successful connection on port `2195`:

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.233.65...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I have tried multiple times with `.pem` certs etc... but I can't make it work. This is the first app I've worked with, so I don't know that much.

I have sent the app along with the wp plugin to a friend in Germany who tested it and got notifications working with his hosting and iPhone.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked the device token is different in develop mode and distribute mode?

Comment: try `telnet` is not enough. Try to SSH with the APNS development certificate with OpenSSH.